# How to create scrollpane with an external .swf file?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, scrollpane

I'm trying to create a simple scrollpane in an external swf (main1.swf) file that links towards my homepage (main.swf), but I'm having trouble with some errors it's generating. First in my external .swf where my scrollpane exists, I added a scrollpane component and I linked the source to a MovieClip that I created, it runs perfectly on my external swf (main1.swf) file but when I go to my homepage (main.swf) and click the button that links to my external swf file (main1.swf), it's generating an error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property fl.managers:IFocusManager::form not found on fl.managers.FocusManager and there is no default value.
    at fl.containers::ScrollPane/setScrollDrag()
    at fl.containers::ScrollPane/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
```

Is there any way you guys can help me fix this error? I've been having a hard time trying to figure out this problem and I really need the help, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var scrollContent_mc:Sprite = Sprite(scroller.content)
```